# 1px dotted border render in IE11/Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, microsoft-edge, dotted-line

Noticed that in IE11/Edge 1px dotted border renders with some issues, in some parts of input it's brighter and in some - darker.

```
input {
  display: block;
  height: 23px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 500px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  color: #C2C2C2;
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

[Image with 1px dotted border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqhhX.png)
even if I increase border -> 2px, the problem still exists.

Chrome/FF looks fine, is that an easy way to solve this, not changing the border type?
https://jsfiddle.net/eehLaogk/11/ (open in IE11/Edge)

Comment: I don't have Edge with me so I can't test, but from the looks of it, it looks like a browser bug. So kudos in finding. Want to file a bug report? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/

Comment: By any chance are you using a high-dpi display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does seem to be a browser bug. I can confirm on `IE11`/`Win7` and it affects other elements, not only `input` fields.

After some testing I found out that the problem occurs when the element's dimensions are **even numbers**, e.g. `500px` wide or `40px` high.

Using odd numbers like `501px` wide and `41px` high is a temporary workaround:

```css
body {
 background: #181818;
}

input {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    color: #C2C2C2;
    background: #000;
    border: 1px dotted #FFF;
    outline: none;
    width: 500px;
}

#input2 { width: 501px; height: 41px; }
```

```html
<input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="500px wide (even)">
<input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="501px wide (odd)">
```

[image: ie11/edge dotted border bug]

Comment: Checked with IE11/Edge on Win10 and it works with odd height/width of input. Thanks.

Comment: Someone has reported the bug here : 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18916402/